# Javascript Garbarge Collection With Objects Containing C++ Elements

Tags: javascript, c++, garbage-collection

At the bottom level HTML elements are C++. When I use Javascript and create a object such as var e = document.getElementsByClassName(), and later no longer use need that object e....it is dereferenced. Typically, garbage collection would clean it out of memory. However, since the object contained C++ code(elements), Javascript grarbarge collection will not be able to clean the object out of memory. I have a couple of questions please:

1. If a web page client is up for, for example, 5 days...and I run e =
   document.getElementsByClassName() once a minute...am I going to have
   the memory full of deferenced objects for the past 5 days?
2. For Google's V8 javascript engine, it is compiled to native machine
   code. Because of this, can it do garbage collection on C++ objects?

Comment: where did you get your understanding of JS's garbage collection? i don't think elements are always c++. some browsers don't even use c++ at all, and some turn eveything into .net IRL objects. V8 doesn't compile everything to machine code, though some structures are converted to assembly. don't take my word for it, try a simple test to see if your computer crashes from running a simple dom call too often.

Comment: Why you say:At the bottom level HTML elements are C++.? I could not find any reference on google for this

Comment: HTML elements are **not** C++ at the "bottom level". HTML is not C++. Browsers can be written in any language, and the underlying implementation has no impact on what a properly implemented garbage collector can and cannot deallocate. Everything about your first paragraph is incorrect, so your two questions are not answerable.

Comment: It's written in my Javascript Book and I have confirmed this also before with other resources.

Answer (score 1):

1. When the Javascript garbage collector determines that an object is garbage, it can use the C++ `delete` operator to reclaim the memory of that object. So you shouldn't leak any memory.
2. Machine code can still call runtime library routines, such as `delete`.